# Ignore content around a field in logstash dissect

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to elasticsearch and logstash. I wrote below code to parse log data similar to below.

Logdate:

```
[[[ LOGTS=2020-07-08 19:23:09, RESULT=P, DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/AB/type/ABCDEFG01, MSGTYPE=ABCDEFG01, MSGORIGIN=BCW1 ]]]
```

Logstash dissect code:

```
mapping => {
          "message" => "[[[ LOGTS=%{LOGTS}, RESULT=%{RESULT}, DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/%{devision_id}/type/ABCDEFG01, MSGTYPE=%{MSGTYPE}, MSGORIGIN=%{MSGORIGIN} ]]]%{innerMessage}"
        }
```

With above lines of code i am getting the devision_id field. but how to ignore the content around division_id field, so that no matter what is the content, i can get only division_id. As I can not specify each and every type of entry.

Similar sample log date:

```
[[[ LOGTS=2020-07-08 19:23:10, RESULT=P, DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/BC/type/BVCDEFG01, MSGTYPE=ABCDEFG01, MSGORIGIN=BCW3 ]]]
[[[ LOGTS=2020-07-08 19:23:11, RESULT=P, DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/CD/type/RTCDEFG01, MSGTYPE=ABCDEFG01, MSGORIGIN=BCW9 ]]]
[[[ LOGTS=2020-07-08 19:23:12, RESULT=P, DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/ZZ/type/BCCDEFG01, MSGTYPE=ABCDEFG01, MSGORIGIN=BCE2 ]]]
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a empty skip field.

For example, something like this:

```
DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/%{division_id}/type/%{},
```

You can also use a named skip field.

```
DESTINATION=mb/cad/division/%{division_id}/type/%{?skipped_field},
```

Both will do the same thing, match the string, but ignore it, the second one just helps you to know what is being skipped if you want to give it a name.